# How can i refresh my DataGrid on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a problem.

I have this WPF GridView

```
<DataGrid 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myOrder.Detail}">
</DataGrid>
```

My property on the viewModel looks like this:

```
public myOrderModel myOrder { get; set; }
```

and this is my model:

```
public partial class myOrderModel
{
    public int ID_Order { get; set; }
    public List<myOrdenDetail> Detail { get; set; }
}
```

On the constructor of the viewmodel y fill my Order with data from a WCF service and the detail is show on the grid correctly (of course this code is simplified). Now I need to modify de Detail collection (add, remove or modify) from inside the viewmodel. The problem is that the gridview is not refreshed to show this changes.

How can i notify the grid to reflect the changes inside Detail List?
Thanks!!!!

**EDIT**

As suggested i try with ObservableCollection and it worked. In the viewModel I add a property:

```
public ObservableCollection<myOrdenDetail> Detail{ get; set; }
```

and Map the model to my new property:

```
Detail = new ObservableCollection<myOrdenDetail>(myOrder.Detail);
```

Of course i need to map Detail back to the original model when I save the information. I could also change the original model behind WCF service but i don't know how would WCF react with ObservableCollection.

Thanks!

Comment: It was some time since I worked with WPF but as far as I can remember the List should be an ObservableCollection and you should use INotifyPropertyChanged event to tell the View to update.

Comment: can you try with `ObservableCollection<myOrdenDetail> Detail` instead of `List<myOrdenDetail> Detail`

Comment: Check this out: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0336be12-6d39-4cfa-8586-c987954e0010/binding-on-datagrid-with-observablecollection?forum=wpf

Comment: Thanks Kyle. See my update.

Answer (score 2):

WPF needs to know that items have changed and `List<T>` does not implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`. If you were to change your `Detail` property to be `ObservableCollection<myOrderDetail>`  then you should be good to go and the grid will update when items get added or removed.

Comment: Ok but to do that i sould change my model behind WCF service. Is ObservableCollection compatible with WCF?